# Preserve tabular separators when using P{'width'}

Tags: tables

I would like to center some of my column values and therefor uses P{'width'}. But this messes up my tabular separators.

Latex:

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}|P{1cm}}
        \textbf{Sentences} & \textbf{the} & \textbf{red} & \textbf{dog} & \textbf{cat} & \textbf{eats} & \textbf{food} \\
         \hline
             the red dog    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
             cat eats dog   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
             dog eats food  & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
             red cat eats   & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Output:

[image]

How do I preserve the separation lines?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the `P` column type?

Comment: Please also clarify what you mean by "tabular separators".

Comment: you have not show the definition of P column.  the standard p column specification does not produce the result you show so whatever the issue is, it is in code you have not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand what you want, it can be obtained with the recently defined column type `wc`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{float}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}*{6}{|wc{1cm}}}
            \textbf{Sentences} & \textbf{the} & \textbf{red} & \textbf{dog} & \textbf{cat} & \textbf{eats} & \textbf{food} \\
             \hline
                 the red dog & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
                 cat eats dog & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
                 dog eats food & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
                 red cat eats & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks!